# Introducing shared pointer to reduce thread contention

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class that holds a shared pointer to a map.

**Code snippet:**

```
class SomeClass {
  private:
    shared_ptr<const map<int, string>> sptr_;
    ReaderWriterLock rw_lock_;
  public:
    SomeClass() : sptr_(make_shared<const map<int, string>>()) {};
    void UpdateSharedPointer(shared_ptr<const map<int, string>>&& new_sptr) {
      if (!new_sptr) { return; }
      rw_lock_.Lock(true /* is_writer */);
      sptr_ = move(new_sptr);
      rw_lock_.Unlock();
    }
    void ReadSharedPointer() const {
      rw_lock_.Lock(false /* is_writer */);
      // Create a copy of the pointer.
      shared_ptr<const map<int, string>> local_sptr = sptr_;
      rw_lock_.Unlock();
      if (!local_sptr) {
        return;
      }
      // Read the map object pointed by the local_sptr and perform some operations.
    }
}
```

**Usage pattern:** An instance of `SomeClass` can be accessed by multiple threads. And I am okay working on a stale copy of map inside `ReadSharedPointer()` method.

The use of shared pointer to a constant map object leads to a less contentious code. If someone needs to update or read the map, the lock is held for only a short while. Instead, if I eliminate the shared pointer, any map update or read will need to hold the `rw_lock_` for a larger time.

What I am worried about is that this extra pointer indirection might make the code fragile. For example, my current use case requires only a constant map, but if in future someone updates the map to be a non-const object and forgets to update the locking mechanism associated with the read operation, a race condition might get introduced.

Also, one might argue that eliminating the shared pointer makes the complete workflow simpler to understand. And a shared pointer might not make sense if we are not truly sharing this map but only introducing a shared pointer to reduce contention.

**So basically my questions are:**

> How good of a design is this? What are the pros and cons? Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no objective answer to this type of question. It will definitely be closed for being opinion based.

Comment: You already have a potential issue right now, as the contents of the shared pointer in the Update method can happen after you have obtained the local copy in the Read method and done whatever processing you want to perform.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is already thread safe for copying and assignment.  However it does __not__ protect the data it owns from race conditions.  So if you copy the `std::shared_ptr` and use the copy on another thread to access the data it controls you still need memory fences.

Comment: Your concern about changing the `shared_ptr` to point to a non-const map is valid, but doing so in general is a breaking change. You cannot safely change a `shared_ptr<const T>` to a `shared_ptr<T>` without reviewing everywhere that uses the pointer. It removes an important guarantee that other code is likely to depend on. Anyone who makes this change is responsible for making sure it doesn't break anything.

Comment: What precisely do you mean with "thread safe", @RichardCritten? Pretty much everything from the C++ standard library is thread-safe, but that may not mean what many people naively assume it means.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the control block.

Comment: If you're worried about someone forgetting to adjust your function when changing the element type from const to non-const, simply add `static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(sptr_)::element_type>, "Changing to non-const element type requires an update of this function");` This will result in a compiler error, if the function is not updated... Btw: why not use `std::shared_mutex`? No need to implement this on your own.

Comment: @RichardCritten The idea here is to only have `shared_ptr` to instances that are never mutated. In this case, there is no need to synchronize reading from the object. If the map has to change, a new copy is made, the changes applied and the new instance replaces the old one. Some threads may now have pointers to a stale object, but for some applications this is okay.

Comment: Just a suggestion: If you accept a `unique_ptr<map>`, it can't happen that anyone still has a `shared_ptr<map>` somewhere allowing them to write to it without synchronization. Internally, you store it as a `shared_ptr<map const>` still, which you can then share with other threads. You could also accept a `map&&`, now that I think about it, maybe that's even simpler.

Comment: in `sptr_ = move(new_sptr);` you're still destroy the old map while holding the lock

Comment: Not a problem, @appleapple. Firstly, the map only gets destroyed if you were holding the last reference in the member. If that's the case, it's not shared with anywhere else, so destroying it is fine.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it'd take more time holding the lock.

Comment: @appleapple: Can you describe with a few more words what scenario you have in mind where that causes problems? I don't understand what you intend to say.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think their comment is about swapping the old map out of the member instead of simply assigning the new pointer to it, then to actually reset the old map's pointer, which would now be held in a local `shared_ptr` variable, after unlocking. It's a micro optimization.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt exactly as what @ FrançoisAndrieux said, I point it out because OP said "the lock is held for only a short while", not really the case if you still need to destroy it. (not talking about if the whole class is a good idea)

Comment: @RichardCritten @Francois Andrieux correctly described the idea. I am okay reading a stale map, and since the map object `sptr_` and `local_sptr` point to are constant, I am not worried about the protecting the data pointed to by the shared pointer. That's the optimization.

Comment: @appleapple it's a good suggestion to destroy the map outside the lock.

Comment: (1) For correct updates to a shared non-thread-safe data structure, the keyword to look up is definitely RCU.

Comment: (2) The design is _bad_ (i.e. inefficient). Instead of possibly blocking locks, a better construct is [`atomic<shared_ptr<...>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). Context: While multiple `shared_ptr` instances (pointing at the same `shared_ptr` body with its atomic reference counter and raw pointer) are “mutually thread-safe” (and can be owned by different threads), one `shared_ptr` is **not** thread-safe. The `atomic<shared_ptr<...>>` closes the gap: You can `atomic_exchange()` it without locking, relying on `shared_ptr`s in readers / assigners to cooperate.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek This was suggested in another related question, but OP's local conventions do not allow `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`. It is a C++20 feature which is frequently not supported yet by organisations.

Comment: If you don't have C++20, you can use [`std::atomic_load`/`std::atomic_store`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), e.g.: <https://godbolt.org/z/Mh6GMe8T4>. I think there are some libraries with more granular locking on maps which might be appropriate depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That’s (also) why I provided a link to [the page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) that lists the pre-C++20 API for atomic operations on a `shared_ptr` and explains how those atomic function overloads were deprecated in C++20 in favor of `atomic<shared_ptr<...>>`. So C++20 is definitely not strictly required, although it does make things “more consistent”.